# Java: Waiting for a mouseClickedEvent

Tags: java

I am writing a program where users answer questions by clicking on `JTable` cells. If the question is answered correctly/incorrectly, the `MouseListener`    changes the value of answeredResult. The program will keep running until there are no available questions (the `available` array list contains a list of `Items`, which is a class I created that contains strings event, year, and description, called by `getEvent()`, `getYear()`, and `getDescription()` methods respectively). However, for each question, I want to wait until a `mouseClickedEvent` is detected before executing the proceeding code (see below).

I know that adding another while loop for waiting is really bad. I've also seen 
some answers suggesting to put whatever I want to do in the `mouseClicked` method, but I don't know how in my case, since I want to repeat it multiple times.

I think another problem is that the program is stuck in the while(available.size()!=0) loop. So it cant detect the mouse click.

Any suggestions on how to make this work?

```
ArrayList<Item> available = new ArrayList<Item>();
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    available.add(new Item("Event " + i, "Year " + i, "Description " + i));
}

JTable table = new JTable(model);
table.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        int row = table.rowAtPoint(evt.getPoint());
        int col = table.columnAtPoint(evt.getPoint());    
        if (row >= 0 && col == 2 && canPlay) {
            clickedYear = (String)data[row][col];
            if(clickedYear.equals(answerYear)){ 
                answeredResult = 1;                        
            }else{
                answeredResult = -1;
            }
        }
     }
});

while(available.size()!=0){
    promptPanel.removeAll();
    answeredResult = 0; //0-unanswered 1-correct 2-incorrect

    int random = (int)(Math.random()*(available.size()-1));
    JLabel label = new JLabel(available.get(random).getEvent()+"\n");
    promptPanel.add(label);    
    canPlay = true;    

    //wait for mouse clicked before proceeding to the next code

    if(answeredResult == 1){
        JLabel correct = new JLabel("Correct!");
        promptPanel.add(correct);
    }else if(answeredResult == -1){
        JLabel wrong = new JLabel("Wrong.");
        promptPanel.add(wrong);
    }

    revalidate();
    repaint();           
    available.remove(random);
}
```

Comment: Either have a method you can call or separate the `MouseListener` into a separate which can handle the functionality you need.  GUIs are event driven, so you need to change the way you are thinking to accomidate that flow

Comment: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We don't even know what type the variable "available" is, and we never see any code adding data to it. And MadProgrammer is right; you can't hog the event thread like that, the GUI would stop responding.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I see now your point that GUIs are event driven. But what do you mean by separating the mouse listener? I'm still a bit confused, so I would really appreciate if you could give me a clearer explanation/example. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, if you don't want to run all the logic in the `mouseClicked` method, which is not a bad thing, you could create a custom class, which implements `MouseListener` or extends `MouseAdapter`, takes in the required object references and performs the functionality you want, equally, you could just create one or more methods which performs the operations you want in the current class and call these from your `mouseClicked` method